# Visual Query Builder

Tags: mysql, windows

If been using "dbForge Query Builder" lately and I'm gotten used to the ease of building and testing a query, specially for those complex ones with inner joins, aliases and multiple conditionals.

The expiry date of the trial is about to come, and while wanting to remain on the legal side for this I'd rather not pay the 50USD it costs (although I must say it's pretty cheap for what it does).

So my question would be: Are there any free alternatives to replace this visual query builder? I've failed to find any and fear that my only two options are paying for it, or going to the dark side.

Comment: Not everybody agree questions like this get out voted every time by the smarty pants

Comment: This is legitimate question!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You may try [FlySpeed SQL Query](http://www.activedbsoft.com/overview-querytool.html). It has the same powerful visual query builder and it's free if you don't need data export and printing.

Comment: No its not free at all. need to buy it

Answer (score 6):

You should try [SQLyog](http://www.webyog.com/en/downloads.php), it has powerful visual query builder. It is very easy and intuitive to use.

[image: SQLyog Query Builder Screenshot]

Comment: SQLyog's Visual Query Builder is only currently available in the Enterprise and Ultimate versions, which are not free. https://www.webyog.com/product/sqlyogFeatureListExpanded/

Comment: It seems that this product no longer provide visual query builder functionality in the free version.

Answer (score 5):

I have found [SQLeo](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqleo/), which I will use to show my colleagues how to build SQL queries. It is Java-based, so it will run on virtually any platform.

You will also need to install [MySQL's Java Connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) for SQLeo to be able to connect.

Answer (score 3):

Think of it in terms of how much money/time it will help you make/save in the long run. Consider it a business expense. Yes, there are other free query builders out there, but they all take time to learn/get used to. If your happy with this one I'd say go for it.

That aside there generally are several ways you can reinstall the program and get one more month out of your free-trial if your still not quite sure its worth it.

Answer (score 2):

Try [EasyQueryBuilder](http://easyquerybuilder.com).

It requires some configuration for your database at start but after that it's very easy to build queries with this tool - even for non-experienced users.

Answer (score 2):

dbForge has an express version for MySQL that is free.  I use the express version for MSSQL all the time.

Answer (score -2):

EASY QUERY BUILDER is anything but easy if you're using MYSQL.  Building a connection is impossible and their documentation is nonexistent.  Don't waste your time.

Comment: Installation AND connection took me less than a minute (mysql). How do you manage not being able to connect ?