# MYSQL GROUP BY / ORDER BY confusion

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I am trying to sort my results but my order by statement is being ignored... I understand why but not how to fix it. Here is my code:

```
SELECT 
    result.station_id as 'Station ID',
    result.date as 'Date',
    result.id as 'ID',
    COALESCE(sum(if(result.parameter = '1', result.result, NULL)),'-') as 'RESULT A)',
    COALESCE(sum(if(result.parameter = '2', result.result, NULL)),'-') as 'RESULT B)',
FROM (  
    SELECT
        event.station_id,
        event.date,
        event.id,
        e_result.result
    FROM event
    Inner Join e_result ON e_result.id = event.id
    WHERE 
         (event.station_id =  '0001') AND `devent`.`date` >= '1999-02-08' AND `event`.`date` <= '2011-12-20') as result 
GROUP BY by result.id
ORDER BY 
     result.station_id ASC, 
     result.date DESC
```

It is grouping correctly but not sorting the results afterwards... It seems to be sorting the groupings. I need the whole result set (not each grouping) sorted after the grouping is finished

Sample output:

```
Station Date        ID          Result A    Result B
20      7/6/2009    g003        -           3
12      2/8/1999    g000        19.2        -
12      2/8/1999    g001        19.9        -
12      2/14/1999   g002        19.1        -
17      4/9/2003    i001        22.2        4
```

Should be

```
Station Date        ID          Result A    Result B
12      2/14/1999   g002        19.1        -
12      2/8/1999    g000        19.2        -
12      2/8/1999    g001        19.9        -
17      4/9/2003    i001        22.2        4
20      7/6/2009    g003        -           3
```

Tables:

```
e_result   id, parameter, result
     g002, 1, 19.1
     g000, 1, 19.2
     g001, 1, 19.9
     i001, 1, 22.2
     i001, 2, 4
     g003, 2, 3

event      station_id, date, id
     20, 7/16/2009, g003
     12, 2/8/1999, g000
     12, 2/8/1999, g001
     12, 2/14/1999, g002
     17, 4/9/2003, i001
```

Comment: Show us some output that you feel is incorrectly sorted.  In general, `ORDER BY` clauses will be applied last, after the result set has been generated, so it's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: @MikeRyan I think they want the ORDER BY completed prior to the grouping

Comment: This does not answer your question exactly, but might help - Using graphical query builders would make it a lot easy to build such complex queries in mysql without errors. Take a look at this post on SO - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506610/visual-query-builder

Comment: @bluefeet Well, that may be what the OP _thinks_ they want.  But how would sorting before applying `GROUP BY` accomplish anything?  It's still going to combine rows based upon the group by criteria.  Thus, we'd need to see some output -- I suspect the real problem is confusion about what `GROUP BY` really means.

Comment: @MikeRyan totally agree that they appear to be confused.

Comment: I added output... yes I understand what group by mean... the problem is the sorting after the grouping is finished.

Comment: @KatherineC What is the output when you remove the `ORDER BY` clause?

Comment: @MikeRyan No change... I've tried that, and placing everything up to the order by in a SELECT * FROM type sub query then trying to sort that result set but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: @KatherineC Would it be possible to create an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) for this?  With just enough data to see the effect.  They have mysql as a db option.  Or edit your question to add  the original table's schema and just enough test data to see the effect.

Comment: I'm thinking this has to do with having the non-aggregate columns missing from your `GROUP BY`.  Try putting all three values into your `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: @MikeRyan that returned only one record

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? I'm wondering if you could've hit this bug: [http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=32202](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=32202)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have put your query into sqlfiddle, but had to do a lot of adjusting to make it work.

Here is a query that produces the result you want:

```
select result.station_id as 'Station ID',
    date_format(result.date,'%c/%m/%Y') as 'Date',
    result.id as 'ID',
    if (sum(if(result.parameter = 1, result.result,0)) = 0, 
        null, 
        sum(if(result.parameter = 1, result.result,0)))  as 'RESULT A)',
    if (sum(if(result.parameter = 2, result.result,0)) = 0, 
        null, 
        sum(if(result.parameter = 2, result.result,0)))  as 'RESULT B)'
from 
      (SELECT
        event.station_id,
        event.date,
        event.id,
        e_result.result,
        e_result.parameter
      FROM event
      Inner join e_result ON e_result.id = event.id) as result
group by 
     result.station_id, result.date, result.id
order by 
     result.station_id ASC, 
     result.date DESC;
```

I reworked the coalesce, I removed the where clause on the inner table result, corrected the 'devent' typo, added the parameter field to the inner table. and a few other things

This gives:

```
STATION ID    DATE         ID      RESULT A    RESULT B
12            2/02/1999    g002    19.1    
12            2/02/1999    g000    19.2    
12            2/02/1999    g001    19.9    
17            4/04/2003    i001    22.2        4
20            7/07/2009    g003                3
```

It's all here:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/34d87/17

Comment: Thank you... sorry about the typos and such... this is a stripped down version of the real query but your solution helped! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can see you don't understand how `group by` works. When you group by, you lose individual records and put them together in a bag, which allows you to perform aggregate functions, such as `count`, `sum`, etc. So, as a rule of thumb, if you are selecting a non-aggregated field, then you should put it in the `group by` clause.

In your example you're not using any aggregate function so, why would you group?

Additionally, you're having issues with data types. Your `station_id` in your query seems to be a string, while in the output seems to be an integer. The other way around happens with your dates. My bet is that you're using character fields instead of the appropriate data type for those fields and you're getting them ordered as character fields.

Comment: the group by is grouping the event results as expected. yes the data is not the right type... I neither set it up nor can I change it now.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is fine, but is missing one last function in the end:

```
GROUP BY
 result.station_id
```