# About mysql views, relationship and any other related column to column thing

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Guys can you suggest me any **software** who have some similarities with

**Microsoft's SQL SERVER**

I want to use the view part of SQL SERVER. **To make it clear,** I'm using **MYSQL** as back end so I wonder if there's something similar functionality with **SQL SERVER** for **MY SQL**

I mean this one:

[image: SQL SERVER's VIEW for MYSQL]

> Does mysql have this kind of functionality? If yes, what is it? If no,
> can sql server support or can be used as mysql? How?

**Please don't give me links I wanna learn not through a lot of links. Thank you so much guys... :)**

Comment: See: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506610/visual-query-builder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506610/visual-query-builder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not "SQL Server". That's just the graphical frontend known as MSSMS - ms sql server management studio. Look into [PHPMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php), which is one of many grpahical front-ends for MySQL.

Comment: Dear mate, you just saved my day. I wonder why I haven't look thorough with phpmyadmin. Thanks much!

Comment: Mate! I gotta  problem here how do you do designer in phpmyadmin? I can't seem to find it @Marc B

Answer (score 0):

See the answers to this question concerning Visual Query Builder for MySQL: [Visual Query Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506610/visual-query-builder)